# WooCommerce limited role

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

I'm trying to make a custom Woocommerce role that only has access to the WooCommerce reports. The role needs to be able to see the sales reports, but not edit products or anything else on the website.

I tried creating a custom role, but when logging in with that role, I get this error: `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

Here is what I tried:

```
add_role('woo_limited', 'Woo Limited', array(
  'read' => true,
  'view_woocommerce_reports' => true,
));
```

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: some help with this url:-https://toolset.com/course-lesson/custom-woocommerce-roles-admin-capabilities/

Comment: @AshvinMonpara Thanks but that doesnt help